# Run SQL statement based on sql count

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I want to run one SQL query based on first COUNT sql query:

```
SET @result = "SELECT count(*) FROM ip_addresses WHERE id > (SELECT id FROM ip_addresses WHERE in_use=1) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1"
CASE WHEN (@result > 0)
    THEN SELECT * FROM ip_addresses WHERE id > (SELECT id FROM ip_addresses WHERE in_use=1) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
    ELSE SELECT * FROM ip_addresses WHERE in_use!=1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
END
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is, I want to get the next record `in_use=0` of `WHERE in_use=1`. And if the `in_use=1` record is last record of the table it should get the first record of table with `in_use=0`.
More explaination:
if `ip_addresses` table have following data

```
 id|     ip     |in_use
 1 | 192.168.1.5|1
 2 | 89.58.1.2  |0
 3 | 58.98.58.6 |0
```

Now it should return second record.

And if `ip_addresses` table have following data

```
 id|     ip     |in_use
 1 | 192.168.1.5|0
 2 | 89.58.1.2  |0
 3 | 58.98.58.6 |1
```

Now it should return first record.

Comment: In english, what are you after?  The IP of the lowest ID not in use?

Comment: @xQbert check my updates in the question

Comment: in his current query, if the middle ip is in use, the last ip would be returned, not the first.

Comment: I want to get the next ip of `in_use= 1` ip. if `in_use= 1` is the last record of the table I want to get the first `in_use= 0` record of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues.  The most important is that control flow logic is only allowed in programming blocks.

However, you can accomplish what you want with a single query.  For instance:

```
(SELECT ia.*, 1 as priority
 FROM ip_addresses ia
 WHERE id > (SELECT id FROM ip_addresses WHERE in_use = 1)
 ORDER BY id
 LIMIT 1
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT ia.*, 2 as priority
 FROM ip_addresses ia
 WHERE in_use <> 1
 ORDER BY id
 LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY priority
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on xQbert's answer:

```
select  IP
from   ( select case when id >
        ( select min( ID )
          from    IP_ADDRESES
          where   in_use = 1 ) 
        then ID - ( select max( ID ) from IP_ADDRESES )
        else id 
        end case
    from IP_ADDRESES as deflated_id,
    ip )
order by deflated_id asc 
top 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.IP 
  FROM  IP_Addresses A, 
       ( SELECT min(ID) mid
           FROM IP_ADDRESES 
          WHERE in_use= 0
        ) B
WHERE A.id = B.mid;
```

Comment: thanks but its returning me first record of the table while I have in_use= 0 record next to in_use= 1 record

Comment: Please edit your answer to include more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".